# Error while registering to fleet and installing Anthos Service Mesh (Error: local-exec provisioner error)

Tags: kubernetes, terraform-provider-gcp, google-anthos-service-mesh

I am trying to register and install ASM in GCP project. We have shared VPC and we are trying to deploy GKE and ASM in one of the service project. We are using network from host project for the deployment.

GKE setup is already completed using below module :
[GKE Private Cluster Module](https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-kubernetes-engine/tree/master/modules/beta-private-cluster-update-variant)

As a next step we are registering the cluster to the fleet and ASM instalment. For this we are using below module :
[ASM Module](https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-kubernetes-engine/tree/master/modules/asm)

While running the ASM module via github pipeline we are getting below error, looks like it's permission issue, but the service account what we used for provisioning the resource already have "GKE Hub Admin" role.

How to debug and identify the actual problem? Please share your views ?

***ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.get-credentials) ResponseError: code=403, message=Required "container.clusters.get" permission(s) for "".
module.asm.module.asm.module.cpr.module.gcloud_kubectl.null_resource.run_command[0] (local-exec): + cleanup
module.asm.module.asm.module.cpr.module.gcloud_kubectl.null_resource.run_command[0] (local-exec): + rm -rf /tmp/kubectl_wrapper_25817_7345
╷
│ Error: local-exec provisioner error***